# How to enable port for public access?

Tags: tcp, ip, firewall

I have enabled 1 port [8081] and it's accessible from the remote computer. but the same for other port [7500] not working? 
I would like to know the meaning of the below line?

`TCP [::]:8081  [::]:0 LISTENING`

And how to enable the same for port [7500]?

Attached listening port status:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`netstat -na` outputs 4 columns of data:

`Proto`, `Local Address`, `Foreign Address`, and `State`.

When looking for port 8081, you find 2 entries - one for TCP on `0.0.0.0:8081` for IPv4, and one for TCP `[::]:8081` for IPv6.

When looking for port 7500, you find 1 entry - one for TCP `0.0.0.0:7500` for IPv4 only.

In both cases, you have local sockets listening via wildcard IPs to all local network adapters, and there is no "Foriegn Address" assigned because a listening socket is not connected to any remote party.  TCP sockets in the `ESTABLISHED` state have remote parties.

You have not shown any code, or explained your network setup, so nobody can really explain why you have 2 entries for port 8081 but only 1 entry for port 7500, or why remote computers can connect to port 8081 but not to port 7500.  Maybe those clients are only using IPv6?  Maybe your listening computer is behind a router that doesn't forward port 7500?  We don't know.